# PHP convert looping strings to array

Tags: php, arrays, string

How can I convert loop result of string to an array? For instance, I have this strings:

```
$nmbrs = '111, 222, 333, 444';
```

This $nmbrs variable should come from an for loop as that:

```
$numberPrefixes = '__';
 
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) {
     $numbers = $numberPrefixes . randomNumberSequencePhone(); 
}

$array1 = explode(',', $numbers);

var_dump($array1);
```

And I want to get:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "111"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "222"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "333"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "444"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$nmbrs = '111, 222, 333, 444';

$array1 = explode(',', $nmbrs);


var_dump($array1);
?>
```

Comment: This will get extra space for 222, 333 and 444.

Comment: When i do that outside the loop its give me just the first value of the array... 
$numberPrefixes = '__';
 
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) {
  $numbers = $numberPrefixes . randomNumberSequencePhone(); 
}

$array1 = explode(',', $numbers);

var_dump($array1);

Answer (score 1):

`explode(', ', $nmbrs)`

You need the space after the comma so you don't get space character (" ") in your 2nd, 3rd and 4th array items.

Comment: When i do that outside the loop its give me just the first value of the array... $numberPrefixes = '__'; for ($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) { $numbers = $numberPrefixes . randomNumberSequencePhone(); } $array1 = explode(',', $numbers); var_dump($array1);

Comment: It doesn't look like `$numbers` is an array

Comment: That's the point.. I want to convert $numbers to an array? Thanks.

Comment: $numbers is being redefined on every loop iteration

Comment: Aah, so how i can do it?

Comment: Look up php string concatenation